# Nested for loop in JS

Tags: node.js, for-loop, callback, nested

I am trying to implement a nested for loop iterate through over list.
I implement it below code and It works perfectly but I want to know if there is any better way to do this such as using callbacks and async functions.

```
var data = [
    {
    runs: 3,
    items: [
        {
            color: 'green',
            lenth: 10
        }, 
        {
            color: 'black',
            lenth: 15
        }, 
        {
            color: 'blue',
            lenth: 15
        }, 
        {
            color: 'black',
            lenth: 10
        }, 
        {
            color: 'green',
            lenth: 0
        }
    ]},

    {
    runs: 2,
    items: [
        {
            color: 'green',
            lenth: 10
        }
    ]}

];

(async () => {
    for (let exNum = 0; exNum < data.length; exNum++) {
        for (let index = 0; index < data[exNum].runs; index++) {
            console.log('Runs :', index);
            (data[exNum].items).forEach(element => {
                console.log(element.color, " : ", element.lenth);
            });
            console.log('End :', index);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Nothing here in this code is asynchronous - why do you want async functions?

Comment: Actually, I don't need async anymore